# Authenticate to yammer in c# console application

Tags: c#, yammer

Authenticate the user using Yammer API in C# console application ? I don't want in MVC

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myConfig = new ClientConfigurationContainer
    {

        ClientCode = null,
        ClientId = "CODEHERE",
        ClientSecret = "CODEHERE"
    };
    var myYammer = new YammerClient(myConfig);
    var test = myYammer.GetToken();``
    Console.WriteLine("Token" + test);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I am using the NuGet Yammer API and I am trying to simply authenticate and display the token as a test.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it working. I am new to this but there is no documentation on the NuGet Yammer API and it will be a console application. All the examples and documentation on the Yammer developers page show doing this from a web based appication

Answer (score 2):

You cannot authenticate Yammer in C# console application. Yammer authenticates users only in browser and generate tokens using OAuth flow which can be used in your application. https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2